# How to extract arbitrary keys from JSON?

Tags: sql, jinja2, amazon-redshift, dbt

I have a table in redshift where a column called `json_blob` contains data like this

```
|  id | json_blob                                                             |
| --- | --------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| id1 | {"key1": {"name": 1, "type: "foo"}, "keyA": {"name": 2, "type: "bar"}}|
| id2 | {"key2_": {"name": 3, "type: "foobar"}}                               |
| id3 | {"key_3": {"name": 4, "type: "spam"}}                                 |
| .   | .                                                                     |
| .   | .                                                                     |
| .   | .                                                                     |
| idN | {"key-N": {"name": 1005, "type: "ham"}}|
```

The structure of each JSON is pretty consistent minus the fact that the top-level keys are totally arbitrary and not strictly defined (do not ask me why the data producer was designed this way, probably created from user input). I only want to be able to extract the `name` and `type` values but I am struggling on coming up a way on how to do this in `dbt` using Jinja/SQL. Regex will not work here since the actual keys are much different from each other.

I am trying to create this output

```
| id  | name | type |
| --  | ---- | ---- |
| id1 |  1   |  foo |
| id1 |  2   |  bar |
| id2 |  3   |foobar|
| id3 |  4   | spam |
| .   | .    |   .  |
| .   | .    |   .  |
| .   | .    |   .  |
| idN | 1005 |  ham |
```

In Python, I would just have this nested for loop that would do something like this

```py
for row in table:
    for columns in row:
        -- get value from id column
        -- get value from "name" key in json_blob col.
        -- get value from "type" key in json_blob col.
```

But I do not know how to translate this to Jinja in dbt.

Comment: i was able to eventually implement the sudo python code in jinja

Comment: You can use `dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict()` macro and get the result in a dict and iterate in loop anyway you want. [Link to Macro](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/get_query_results_as_dict.sql)